# How to get properties / values from snapshot.val() or snapshot.exportVal() in Firebase?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire

I was able to fetch my interested object as `snapshot` as shown in this [CodePen](http://codepen.io/suman_codepen/pen/NRaXbZ?editors=1010)

Following is the code snippet :

```
$scope.post = {};
        var postsRef = new Firebase('https://docs-examples.firebaseio.com/web/saving-data/fireblog/posts');

        $scope.searchPost = function () {
            console.log('searched for author : ' + $scope.post.authorName);

            postsRef.orderByChild('author')
                .equalTo($scope.post.authorName)
                .once('value', function (snapshot) {
                    var val = snapshot.val();
                    console.log("Searched Post is : ");
                    console.log(val);
                    console.log("(From Val) Title is : " + val.title);

                    var exportVal = snapshot.exportVal();
                    console.log("Export Value is : ");
                    console.log(exportVal);
                    console.log("(From Export Val) Title is : " + exportVal.title);
                });
        }
```

This is the [Firebase dataset](https://docs-examples.firebaseio.com/web/saving-data/fireblog/posts) am using.

When I search for author: `gracehop`, I get the correct snapshot but, I'm not able to access properties like `title` inside that. Both `val.title` & `exportVal.title` are giving `undefined` as output.

How do I get the interested properties from snapshot?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The query returns a snapshot containing the matching children and it is the children that contain the properties in which you are interested.

You can enumerate the children using the snapshot's `forEach` method:

```
postsRef.orderByChild('author')
    .equalTo($scope.post.authorName)
    .once('value', function (snapshot) {

        snapshot.forEach(function (childSnapshot) {

            var value = childSnapshot.val();
            console.log("Title is : " + value.title);
        });
    });
```

Comment: thanks man, it worked. Just a question out of curiosity - when we query data with range using `startAt()` and `endAt()` it makes sense to return array of data but when i use `equalTo()` with any **Unique ID** and am sure of only single object being returned, is there a way to get direct access of that single object like `snapshot.innerObject.title` ?

Comment: Nope. Firebase has no idea of whether or not a value is unique. I just do this sort of thing: `var k, v; snapshot.forEach(function (child) { k = child.key; v = child.val(); return true; }); if (k) { ... }`. The `return true` short circuits the enumeration so that, should it not be unique, you just get the first match.

Comment: Perfecto !! Thanks again :)

Comment: This solution only query the only single and top of the record, how can I get childSnapshot of all the query at the same time. All of them, not 1 of them.